# Access Google Drive API in Python whithout google-api-python-client (installed app)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, httprequest, google-drive-api

I want to make an installed aplication in Python3 to manage the Google Drive files in my google account.

As the official google-api-python-client doesn't support Python3 I've decided to code myself the oauth2 method and access to google drive api with urlib.request.

I managed to pass the authentication process and get the token.  Then I tried to access to the google drive api (copying a file) following the api reference: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId/copy`  with this code:

```
def copy_file(token, target_name):
    print("Access Token: " + token)
    url_target = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Akg4S5DP95FAdFM3VXNJbVo4TjM0MFFGVm5hWlFtU2c/copy"
    request = urllib.request.Request(url_target)
    request.add_header("Authorization", "OAuth" + token)
    request.add_header("title", target_name)
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    print(f.read())
```

I only get 404 error.

When I try with the [Google Api Explorer](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy) it work ok:

```
Request


POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Akg4S5DP95FAdFM3VXNJbVo4TjM0MFFGVm5hWlFtU2c/copy?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.1.AADtN_ULTFZ3jvv962bVVjAYv_GknktRMgvIGAGJPdZ5OAocQANLmN5q_UMq5cA53aqoHBkqo39wHiGM1-pg
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "title": "copia de HiperAgenda"
}

Response


200 OK
```

I've omitted in my code this `?key={YOUR_API_KEY}` Where is my Api Key?

What's my wrong?

Answer (score 2):

## SOLVED

```
def copyFile(token, target_name):
    print("Access Token: " + token)
    url_destino = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/
                  files/0AilPd9i9ydNTdFc4a2lvYmZnNkNzSU1kdVFZb0syN1E/copy
                  ?key=(YOUR_API_KEY provided by Google API Console)"
    values = "{'title': '%'}" % target_name
    data = values.encode('utf-8')
    request = urllib.request.Request(url_destino, data, method='POST')
    request.add_header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
    request.add_header("Content-Length", len(data))
    request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    print(request.header_items())
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    print(f.read())
```

Fixed errors:

- I found my API_KEY in Google API Console.
- HTTP request methond is 'POST'
- The token value start with "Bearer" word, don't "OAuth" (deprecated).
- Parameter requiered isn't a request header.  It's the data of the request.
- The 'data' is json format but binary.
- header "Content-Type: application/json" is requiered
- header "Content-Length: " is requiered

've uploaded a Gist with the completed example fine working: https://gist.github.com/SalvaJ/9722045

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding the value of the `copy` request argument in your Python implementation (i.e. the part in the API explorer that says "`copy?key={YOUR_API_KEY}`"

Comment: I already added the value of key= but the response is a 404 error.